# Verify that moments of gaussian variable are given by a formula

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I would like to ask you to verify if the following statement is true.

Let $X$ be a normal-distributed R.V. with $0$ mean and $\sigma ^2$ variance. Then
$$
    \mathrm{E}\left[X^p\right] =
      \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{if }p\text{ is odd,} \\
        \sigma^p\,(p-1)!! & \text{if }p\text{ is even.}
      \end{cases}
  $$

Is that true?

Comment: Yes it is.${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  First divide $X$ by $\sigma$ to get a standard normal, then use integration by parts noting that $\phi'(y)=-y\phi(y)$. Please note that !! has a special meaning,ie $3!!=3$, $5!!=3*5$, etcetera.